# Wordpress: Create a list of posts within a category

Tags: wordpress, categories

I thought this was going to be simple, but after hours of trying I still can't get it to work.

All I want to do is create a list of links to posts within a specific category and put it in the footer of my site.

Note: I do not want to use yet another plugin!

Comment: If you've been working for hours, please show what you've tried: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You tried [get_posts()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so after getting Dungey140's solution to work this is how I did. This returns the correct URL for the posts too.

```
<?php
    query_posts ( array ( 'post_type' => 'the-post-type', 'category_name' => 'The Category Name', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );

    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); { ?>
      <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php echo the_title(); ?></a></li>

<?php }   
    endwhile;

    wp_reset_query();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

// The Query
query_posts( array ( 'category_name' => 'The Category Name', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );// -1 will display all posts, change to limit posts

// The Loop
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    echo '<li>', '<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( 268 ); ?>">';
    the_title();
    echo '</a>', '</li>';
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had tried something similar before but couldn't get it to work. Turns out, it didn't work because I was querying Custom Post Types. So adding 'post_type' => 'Post Type Name' to the array works perfectly!

Comment: Just out of interest, what does the ( 268 ) do in the get_permalink function? It still seems to work fine without it.

Comment: It's the permalink of page id 268. Youc an replace with any id you wish!